# Change span text on input text and also load it on page load

Tags: jquery

I want to display the text of a input box in a span element.
Additionally I want to load the content of the input box on page load.

Currently I have this code, that is not very short:

```
if( $('#subject').val().length > 0 ) {
    $('#text').text(': '+$('#subject').val());
}

$('#subject').on('input', function() {
    if( $('#subject').val().length > 0 ) {
        $('#text').text(': '+$(this).val());
    } else {
        $('#text').empty();
    }
});
```

Can somebody help me to make this more efficient and small?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trigger the same event on the element, on page load using **[trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)**.

```js
$('#subject').on('input', function() {
  var value = $('#subject').val();
  $('#text').text( value.length > 0 ? ': ' + value : '' );
}).trigger('input');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="text"></span>
<input id="subject" value="asdasdasd">
```

Answer (score 0):

Optimizing of this code doesn't make sense as it's small enough to not make any performance issues. However here is my suggestion for "cleaner" code:

```
var input = $('#subject'),
    span = $('#text');

function onInput() {
    span.text(input.val() ? ':' + input.val() : '');
};
onInput();
$(input).on('input', onInput);
```